# How to send a SMS through a Phone Gap application for the basic version?

Tags: android, sms, cordova, share, phonegap-plugins

I have tried implementing **3 different** plug-in's for this in **cordova-2.1.0**

But nothing has worked out..

**Plugin No:** 1

**source:** [here](https://github.com/Pyo25/phonegap-sms-sending-plugin)

**error faced:** full plugin file rather the java file had errors and had asked to create field names such as cordova call back content...etc

**Plugin No:** 2

**source:**[here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin)

**error faced:** no responsei am able to enter the phone no and message..i am supposed to get an alert with the number and message but did not get it.could not decode

**Plugin No:** 3

**source:**[here](http://androidopera.blogspot.in/2013/03/smsplugin-phonegap-android.html#comment-form)

**error faced:** while i called just this in the sms function**

```
sendSMS.send(‘Mobile Number’, ‘Text’, ‘Call back function on complete’);
```

i got an error of

```
05-31 15:03:05.879: E/Web Console(15239): Uncaught ReferenceError: sendSMS is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:14.
```

when i gave this

```
var sendSMS = {
send : function(phone, message, successCallback, failureCallback) {
return cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SmsPlugin',"SendSMS", [ phone, message ]);
}
};
if (!window.Cordova) {
window.Cordova = cordova;
};
sendSMS.send('Mobile Number', 'Text', 'Call back function on complete');
```

i got a toast message  as **generic failure** and then in the logcat as

```
05-31 15:04:23.082: E/ActivityThread(15400): Activity com.phone.gap.fist proj.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.phonegap.plugins.sms.SmsPlugin$2@414f1068 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the social plugin a common one for SMS,E-MAIL and opening all the social network applications available on your device.

[here](http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/android-phonegap-plugin-for-social-share-email-facebook-twitter-and-sms/)

Its simple to implement.

Comment: Link is down, check the github repo https://github.com/sarathdr/android-share-phonegap1.9

Comment: There's actually this plugin that can be used through PhoneGap Build that probably does the same but is still maintained and for 2.5, 2.7, 2.9, 3.0 and 3.1 to date: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/290